# Conditional logic on function with yield statement and dictionary

Tags: generator, python-2.x, yield

I have a function that looks through a log file. It matches a regular expression in the log file to indicate a new log entry. Once it's done this it then grabs all the information after this point before the next regular expression (which would indicate a new log entry).

For each log entry, some relevant information is placed into a dictionary (error number, error message, etc)

At the end of my createGenerator function I yield mydict because I don't want to store every log entry and then pass it to my second function generatorCheck().

What I want generatorCheck to do is check key, value pairs that have been passed from the createGenerator function. I then want to put all the matching key value pairs into a table. I'm not sure how to do this though as I haven't worked a lot with yield or generators.

```
def createGenerator():
    mydict = {
        'key1': 'value2',
        'key2': 'value3'
        ...
        ...
    }
    yield mydict

def generatorCheck():
    dict2 = {}
    createGenerator()
    for i in createGenerator():
        if 'key1' or 'key2' in createGenerator():
            # store key, value pair in dict2

generatorCheck()
```